# Problemas com chave estrangeira

Tags: java, primefaces, hibernate, java-ee, xhtml

Olá, pessoal. Estou criando um sistema que controla cadastro de usuários e estou com um problema em relação a uma chave estrangeira que é importada de outra classe para a classe Usuários. Na hora que eu altero o combobox do estado, ocorre um erro COULD NOT EXTRACT RESULTSET.

OBS: o meu combobox para selecionar Estado está em relação com o combobox para escolher a cidade. Ou seja, quando é alterado o valor no combobox de estado, os valores disponíveis no combobox de cidade são alterados. Eles estão em dependência.

No arquivo xhtml, na parte do código que define o combobox do estado, existe uma anotação value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.estado}". Se eu tirar o ".usuario", o programa para de dar este erro, mas na hora de salvar, ele não salva o estado. O resto das informações, inclusive a cidade, ele salva normal. Se vocês observarem, todos os outros campos utilizam ".usuario" no value. Não sei por que somente o campo Estado está dando este problema.

**CadastroUsuario.xhtml**

```
<ui:define name="titulo">#{cadastroUsuarioBean.editando ? "Editar Cadastro de Usuário" : "Novo Usuário"}</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">
<f:metadata>
    <o:viewParam name="usuario" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario}"/>
    <f:event listener="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.inicializar}" type="preRenderView"/>
</f:metadata>


<h:form>
    <h1>#{cadastroUsuarioBean.editando ? "Editar Cadastro de Usuário" : "Novo Usuário"}</h1>

    <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true"/>

    <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
        <p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:button value="Novo" outcome="/usuario/CadastroUsuario" disabled ="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.editando}"/>
            <p:commandButton value="Salvar" id="botaoSalvar" action="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.salvar}" update="@form" />
        </p:toolbarGroup>
        <p:toolbarGroup align ="right">
            <p:button value="Pesquisar" outcome="/usuario/PesquisaUsuario"/>
        </p:toolbarGroup>
    </p:toolbar>

    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px" 
    columnClasses="rotulo, campo">

        <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
        <p:inputText id="nome" size="60" maxlength="60"
        value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.nome}" required="true" requiredMessage="Por favor, informe seu nome" validatorMessage="formato de nome inválido">
        <f:validateRegex pattern="^[A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]+$"/>
        </p:inputText>

        <p:outputLabel value="Senha" for="senha"/>
        <p:password id="senha" size ="10" maxlength="6" required="true" requiredMessage="Por favor, informe uma senha" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.senha}" match="senha2" validatorMessage="As senhas informadas não coincidem. Por favor, informe-as novamente"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Verifique sua senha" for="senha"/>
        <p:password id="senha2" size ="10" maxlength="6" required="true" requiredMessage="Confirme sua senha" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.senha}" match="senha2"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="RG" for="rg"/>
        <p:inputText id="rg" size="20" maxlength="20"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.rg}" required="true" requiredMessage="por favor, preencha o número do seu RG"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="CPF" for="cpf"/>
        <p:inputMask id="cpf" size="14" maxlength="14"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.cpf}" mask="999.999.999-99" required="true" requiredMessage="Por favor, informe seu CPF"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Email" for="email"/>
        <p:inputText id="email" size="50" maxlength="50"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.email}" required="true" requiredMessage="Por favor, informe um email para contato" validatorMessage="formato de email inválido">

        <f:validateRegex
            pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
        </p:inputText>

        <p:outputLabel value="Telefone para contato" for="telefone"/>
        <p:inputMask id="telefone" size="14" maxlength="14"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.telefone}" mask="(99)9999-9999" required="true" requiredMessage="Por favor, informe um telefone para contato"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Celular para contato" for="celular"/>
        <p:inputMask id="celular" size="14" maxlength="14"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.celular}" mask="(99)999999999" required="true" requiredMessage="Por favor, informe um celular para contato"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Estado" for="estado"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="estado" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.estado}" label="Estado" filter="true" 
        filterMatchMode="contains" required="true" requiredMessage="Por favor, escolha um estado">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Estado" noSelectionOption = "true"/>
            <f:selectItems 
                value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.listEstados}" var="estado"
                itemValue="#{estado}"  itemLabel="#{estado.estado_sigla}" />
            <p:ajax listener="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.carregarCidades}" update="cidade"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel value="Cidade" for="cidade"/>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="cidade" value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.cidade}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione a cidade"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.listCidades}" var ="cidade"
            itemValue="#{cidade}" itemLabel="#{cidade.cidadeNome}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>

        <p:outputLabel value="CEP" for="cep"/>
        <p:inputMask id="cep" size="8" maxlength="8"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.cep}" mask="99999-999" required="true" requiredMessage="Por favor, informe o CEP de seu endereço"/>

        <p:outputLabel value="Endereço" for="endereco"/>
        <p:inputText id="endereco" size="100" maxlength="100"
            value="#{cadastroUsuarioBean.usuario.endereco}" required="true" requiredMessage="Por favor, informe um endereço de correspondência"/>
    </p:panelGrid>



</h:form>
</ui:define>
```

**CadastroUsuarioBean.java**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroUsuarioBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private EstadosRep estadosRep;

@Inject
private CidadeRep cidadeRep;

@Inject
private CadastroUsuarioService cadastroUsuarioService;

private Usuario usuario;

private Estado categoriaPai;

private Estado estado;

private Cidade cidade;

private String email;

private List<SelectItem> listEstados;

private List<SelectItem> listCidades;


public CadastroUsuarioBean() {
    limpar();
}

public boolean isEditando() {
    boolean resultado = false;
    if (this.usuario != null) {
        resultado = usuario.getId() != null;
    }
    return resultado;
}


public void inicializar() {
    listEstados = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

    List<Estado> estados = estadosRep.raizes();

    for (Estado e : estados) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.setLabel(e.getEstado_sigla());
        item.setValue(e);
        listEstados.add(item);
    }

    if(!isEditando()){
        usuario.setStatus("Ativo");
    }

    if (this.estado != null) {
        estados = estadosRep.raizes();
    }
}

public void limpar() {
    usuario = new Usuario();
    listEstados = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
}

public void salvar() {
    this.usuario = cadastroUsuarioService.salvar(this.usuario);
    limpar();
    FacesUtil.addInfoMessage("Cadastro de usuário efetuado com sucesso!");
}

public void carregarCidades(){
    listCidades = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    List<Cidade> cidades = cidadeRep.cidadesDe(estado);
    for (Cidade c : cidades) {
        SelectItem item = new SelectItem();
        item.setLabel(c.getCidadeNome());
        item.setValue(c);
        listCidades.add(item);
    }
}

public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
}

public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
}

public Estado getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListEstados() {
    return listEstados;
}

public void setListEstados(List<SelectItem> listEstados) {
    this.listEstados = listEstados;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String register() {
    return "thanks?faces-redirect=true";
}

public Estado getCategoriaPai() {
    return categoriaPai;
}

public void setCategoriaPai(Estado categoriaPai) {
    this.categoriaPai = categoriaPai;
}

public Cidade getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(Cidade cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListCidades() {
    return listCidades;
}

public void setListCidades(List<SelectItem> listCidades) {
    this.listCidades = listCidades;
}   
}
```

**Cidade.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cidade")
public class Cidade {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String cidadeNome;
private Estado estado;

@Id
@Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
public String getCidadeNome() {
    return cidadeNome;
}

public void setCidadeNome(String cidadeNome) {
    this.cidadeNome = cidadeNome;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "estado_sigla")
public Estado getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(Estado estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((cidadeNome == null) ? 0 : cidadeNome.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Cidade other = (Cidade) obj;
    if (cidadeNome == null) {
        if (other.cidadeNome != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!cidadeNome.equals(other.cidadeNome))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

**CidadeRep.java**

```
public class CidadeRep implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject
private EntityManager manager;

public Cidade porNomeCidade(String cidadeNome){
    return manager.find(Cidade.class, cidadeNome);
}

public List<Cidade> raizes(){
    return manager.createQuery("from Cidade", Cidade.class).getResultList();
}

public List<Cidade> cidadesDe(Estado estado){
    return manager.createQuery("from Cidade where estado_sigla = :raiz", Cidade.class)
            .setParameter("raiz", estado).getResultList();
}
}
```

**Estado.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "estado")
public class Estado implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String estado_sigla;
private String estado_nome;

@Id
@Column(nullable = false, length = 2)
public String getEstado_sigla(){
    return estado_sigla;
}

public void setEstado_sigla(String estado_sigla){
    this.estado_sigla = estado_sigla;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getEstado_nome(){
    return estado_nome;
}

public void setEstado_nome(String estado_nome){
    this.estado_nome = estado_nome;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((estado_sigla == null) ? 0 : estado_sigla.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Estado other = (Estado) obj;
    if (estado_sigla == null) {
        if (other.estado_sigla != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!estado_sigla.equals(other.estado_sigla))
        return false;
    return true;
}
}
```

**EstadoRep.java**

```
public class EstadosRep implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Inject 
private EntityManager manager;

public Estado porSigla(String estado_sigla) {
    return manager.find(Estado.class, estado_sigla);
}

public List<Estado> raizes(){
    return  manager.createQuery("from Estado",Estado.class).getResultList(); 
}

public List<Estado> listarEstado() {
    List<Estado> estados = new ArrayList<Estado>();
    estados = manager.createQuery("from Estado", Estado.class).getResultList();
    return estados;
}
}
```

**ConverterUsuarioEstado.java**

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Estado.class)
public class ConverterUsuarioEstado implements Converter {

//@Inject
private EstadosRep estadosRep;

public ConverterUsuarioEstado() {
    estadosRep = CDIServiceLocator.getBean(EstadosRep.class);
}

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

    Estado retorno = null;

    System.out.println("getasobject : "+value);
    if (value != null) {
        String estado_sigla = new String(value);
        retorno = estadosRep.porSigla(estado_sigla);
    }


    return retorno;
}
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null || value.equals("")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            String estado_sigla = ((Estado)value).getEstado_sigla();
            return String.valueOf(estado_sigla);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usuario.java**

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name ="usuario_sequence", sequenceName = "usuario_sequence")
@Table(name = "usuario")
public class Usuario implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long id;
private String nome;
private String senha;
private String status;
private String cpf;
private String rg;
private String email;
private String telefone;
private String celular;
private String endereco;
private Estado estado;
private Cidade cidade;
private String cep;
private List<Grupo> grupos = new ArrayList<>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "usuario_sequence")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 6)
public String getSenha() {
    return senha;
}

public void setSenha(String senha) {
    this.senha = senha;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 14, unique=true)
public String getCpf(){
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf){
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getRg(){
    return rg;
}

public void setRg(String rg){
    this.rg = rg;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getEmail(){
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email){
    this.email = email;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 14)
public String getTelefone(){
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone){
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 14)
public String getCelular() {
    return celular;
}

public void setCelular(String celular) {
    this.celular = celular;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 200)
public String getEndereco(){
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco){
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 9)
public String getCep(){
    return cep;
}

public void setCep(String cep){
    this.cep = cep;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "estado_sigla")
public Estado getEstado(){
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(Estado estado){
    this.estado = estado;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "cidadeNome")
public Cidade getCidade() {
    return cidade;
}

public void setCidade(Cidade cidade) {
    this.cidade = cidade;
}

@NotNull
@Column(nullable = false, length = 7)
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "usuario_grupo", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="usuario_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "grupo_id"))
public List<Grupo> getGrupos() {
    return grupos;
}

public void setGrupos(List<Grupo> grupos) {
    this.grupos = grupos;
}

}
```

Desde já agradeço a qualquer sugestão ou opinião.

Comment: Poderia informar também o código da entidade `Usuario`?

Comment: Victor T. , acabei de postar a classe Usuario.java no fim do meu post.

Comment: verifique se o import do ViewScoped é esse : import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;

Comment: Marcelo, sim. O import do ViewScoped no CadastroUsuarioBean.java é exatamente este que você escreveu.